# New to coding ...I am Looking for a function to delete elements by tag name in html with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I trying to build a script that will clear html documents of specific html tags(Table, td, tr ) but save the data once the tag is removed. 
It would function as a very specific document washer needed for work. Where all the tables are removed from the html doc and then pasted into a custom editor. I want to remove all table elements from the DOM while retaining the contents of those tables. So removing  and preserving the

inside of them.  Each HTML is going to vary greatly part of the issue is there is no standardization with the HTML they all vary greatly in formatting.

```
<script>
    function WashElements() {
        var list = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
        list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
    }
</script>



<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="toc" class="toc" border="1" summary="Contents">
        <tr><td><p>This table is going</p></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

- here is a little html example its basically what were dealing with. We are copying out of a browser window into another editor thats on a separate browser window. I apologize for my lack of clarity this my first stack overflow question, You are all awesome!!

Comment: Please share the html code

Comment: `list` is a HTMLCollection, not an element, so does not have element methods like `removeChild` ... `list[0]` would be the first table element found, so `list[0].removeChild(list[0].childNode[0])` is probably what you want ... simpler code would be `list=document.querySelector('table')` as that would find just the first table in the document, the rest of the code would work then

Comment: However, if you want to remove the first child of all tables ... you'll need to iterate through `list` and perform that removeChild on each entry in list

Comment: If you want these *"pasted"* into an editor need to provide a lot more specific details.

Comment: I cannot share the HTML code because it's an PDF doc that has legal information on it.  There are 1000s of these pdf documents we are exporting to html in batches then copying them into a custom editor to publish them on a website. This is all protected NDA, Legal stuff though so I can't share the exact HTML. In these documents there are multiple tables I need removed. So I am looking for a getter that gets all elements with the table tag them removes them without deleting the data in the table essentially preserving the p tags and losing the table.

Comment: You should make that clear in your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52133547/edit) it. Removing elements from a DOM is one thing. But keeping its contents intact is another! Also, add more details to your question. Show us the HTML form you're planning to use for parsing each HTML code so we know where the result should be. You might also want to add some example code and how it should look after being parsed.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The fact that your code is part of a large pdf with other info is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just create a function with a callback param to achieve what you are looking for:

```
// pass the cb() to save your data in your way, it can be an ajax call or use localStorage, caches etc
function clearDOMandDoStuff(cb) {
   var elem = document.querySelector('YOUT_TAG'); // can be class, id, or tag
   var data = elem.innerHTML;  // let's say you wanna save html content
   if (cb) {
      cb(data); 
   }
   elem.innerHTML = ''; // clear the element body
}

function saveData(data) {
  if (window.localStorage) {
     localStorage.setItem("mydata", data);
  } else {
     // call other saving functions
  }
}
```

And you can wrap them up and put it in your code:

```
clearDOMandDoStuff(saveData);
```

Comment: Read the comments. He wants the contents of the removed elements to remain intact. I haven't actually tested it, but if I remember correctly, `removeChild()` will remove the contents as well.

Comment: I guess you are right, I will update the answer. It will simply need to set innerHTML to be empty in that case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will do exactly what you need. Explanation in comments:

```
function parseHTML(html, elements){
    // Parse the HTML
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

    // Loop through each element that should be removed
    for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        // Get all elements that need to be removed
        let element = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(elements[i]), index;

        // Loop through each element
        for (index = element.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            let parent = element[index].parentNode;
            // Copy the contents of the element to be removed to its parent so it doesn't get lost
            while( element[index].firstChild ) {
                parent.insertBefore( element[index].firstChild, element[index] );
            }
            // Remove the element
            element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
        }
    }

    // Save the result
    let result = htmlDoc.documentElement.outerHTML;

    // Show the result in the console
    console.log(result);
}

// Array of elements to remove
const arr = ['table','tr','td'];

// HTML string to parse
const str = "<body><div><table><tr><td><p>test</p></td></tr></table></div></body>";

parseHTML(str, arr);
```